# Blender 3D render Java servlet interface

Tags: java, servlets, render, blender

I need to make 3D render a still image in a server.  I was advised that Java servlet would do it.  I was studying it for quick prototype and am stuck.

How should I call Blender in Java??

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/HelloworldInServlet")
public class HelloworldInServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Run Blender on server (localhost for now)
        // I need something here??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the most simple solution i can think of looks like this:

```
public class RenderSceneServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String outputFile = "/path/to/output-file";

        // execute command to render a frame from scene.blend
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process exec = runtime.exec("blender -b scene.blend -o " + outputFile + " -F JPEG -x 1 -f 1");

        // wait for blender to finish
        exec.waitFor();

        // serve the rendered file
        File file = new File(outputFile);
        byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
    }
}
```

you should keep few things in mind:

- use a alternating name for `outputFile` otherwise concurrent request will override the file every time.
- [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) is a class from apache commons-io
- i am not really familiar with blender, so the command line "blender -b scene.blend -o [...]" may need some additional attention.

Comment: at byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file); I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.  I have .jar in buildpath and classpath.  Some research told me, runtime and compile classpaths might be different.  How should I resolve it??

Comment: @nelmMNT either you put the `commons-io` jar in thte lib folder of youer servlet container (=server) or you put it inside your application in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/804521/yevgeniy I made it worked.  Thanks.  Now I want to use request.getParameter("scene") to select which 3D scene to render.  There could be 5 input parameters.  So putting all in URL might be a overburden (GET).  How can I send it with POST?? I researched only to find <form action=""> <input type ....>.  Should I hard code it in my HTML??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: please use google to find tutorials on `handling form data in servlet`. if your parameters are "simple" values, like integers or short strings you maybe should stick to GET. with GET you can provide links like your-host/HelloworldInServlet?scene=foo.blend&output=foo.jpg and you do not need a form or javascript to call your servlet.

Comment: Simple GET method worked.  Thanks.  So I assume, it will handle many client requests at a time when I put my Java code in a server.  What about a software run in a server that require license? Do Java thread get generated and run one software for million users?

Comment: @nelmMNT sorry, i simply just don't understand your both questions. somehow you are concerned about licenses... don't need to. stick to oracle jdk + tomcat and you are good to got. should be enough for you requirements. your second question is not so easy to answer. whether a thread is created for every request or not depends on the server you use. most modern server use more effective methods then 1-thred-per user.